# How to get formated datetime string based on date&time formats setting of OS in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

Below figure shows the windows setting for the date&time formats. I want to use this format to display formatted date&time string by using function `strftime()`. And it should work on python 3.4 and later version without OS admin rights. How can I get date and time formats that have been set in the windows system in python3? Or is there any equivalent method to get the formated datetime string?

[image]

I tried to use `win32api.GetDateFormat` and `win32api.GetTimeFormat`, but it doesn't work well. The behavior of these two methods are different on python 3.4 and python 3.9. In python 3.9, below code works when year >= 1970

```py
>>> win32api.GetTimeFormat(0,0, datetime.datetime(1969,11,20,1,2,3))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>> win32api.GetTimeFormat(0,0, datetime.datetime(1970,11,20,1,2,3))
'5:02:03 PM'
```

In python 3.4, above code will raise an `ValueError`. But it can be fixed by setting timezone. And `GetDateFormat` only works when year > 1600.

```
(Pdb) win32api.GetTimeFormat(0,0, datetime.datetime(1970,11,20,1,2,3))
*** ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime
(Pdb) win32api.GetDateFormat(0, 0,datetime.datetime(1601,10,10,1,2,3).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC')))
'10/10/1601'
(Pdb) win32api.GetTimeFormat(0, 0,datetime.datetime(1601,10,10,1,2,3).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC')))
'1:02:03 AM'
(Pdb) win32api.GetTimeFormat(0, 0,datetime.datetime(1600,10,10,1,2,3).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC')))
'1:02:03 AM'
(Pdb) win32api.GetDateFormat(0, 0,datetime.datetime(1600,10,10,1,2,3).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC')))
*** pywintypes.error: (87, 'GetDateFormat', 'The parameter is incorrect.')
(Pdb) win32api.GetDateFormat(0, 0,datetime.datetime(1601,10,10,1,2,3).replace(tzinfo=pytz.timezone('UTC')))
'10/10/1601'
```

**Is there any way that I can easily to generate formatted datetime string based on setting of OS in python 3.4+?**

Comment: @MrFuppes My goal is to get formatted string of a `datetime` where the format should based on operating system's setting. I'll try your way, but to access the registry is too complicated. Is there an easy way?

Comment: *"My goal is to get formatted string*" - that's something different than the formatting directive - which your question "*How can I get date and time formats*" implies. So, what is it you need?

Comment: @MrFuppes, I'm not a native English speaker. So my expression may not be accurate. My final goal is to generate a formatted string for a datetime type object. But the format should be from operating system's setting. When user of the python script has different date and time format setting in operating system, the output formated string should be different. The registry way should not work, because the user may not have admin rights of OS.

Comment: @MrFuppes I updated the question title and description. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: ok that clarifies things :) I don't think you want to do the registry hack for that. Although I believe no elevated rights would be required for it, it would definitely not be easy.